# Unable to create a controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, rubygems, runtime-error

```
C:\Sites\blog\bin>rails generate controller Welcome index
```

I am trying to create a controller for my blog application. When i run the command i get the below error.

Is uninstalling the only option here?

```
C:/Sites/blog/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:15:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `to_time_preserves_timezone=' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in 
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-`require_application_and_environment!'

        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what version of rails are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are on Windows version of Rails and now you're trying the official Rails'guide. It means you haven't created anything else by now.
Before reinstalling Rails I think you should try `bundle install` command.
If this won't work out - try reinstalling.